# How to update multicolumn in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to write a SQL update query. I want to update `where workorder=12300000` column1.TrimStart(B7CL).Addto(column2). But how can I do that in SQL Server 2005?

Convert this table:

```
workorder |column1            | column2         
12300000  |B7CL-B32-41-00-5A  | NULL
12400000  |B7CL-B33-42-00-5A  | NULL
12300000  |B7CL-B34-44-03-5A  | NULL
12600000  |B7CL-B35-45-01-5A  | NULL
12300000  |B7CL-B36-45-01-5A  | B36-45-01-5A
```

To this table:

```
workorder |column1            | column2
12300000  |B7CL-B32-41-00-5A  | B32-41-00-5A
12400000  |B7CL-B33-42-00-5A  | B33-42-00-5A
12300000  |B7CL-B34-44-03-5A  | B34-44-03-5A
12600000  |B7CL-B35-45-01-5A  | B35-45-01-5A
12300000  |B7CL-B36-45-01-5A  | B36-45-01-5A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Update Table
    Set Column2 = Replace(Column1, 'B7CL-','')
    Where Column2 Is Null
    AND workorder=12300000
```

Comment: @Dan - Thanks Dan, missed that off.

Comment: @Dan Grossman: yes, that's what the OP requested in the question, **BUT** his sample doesn't seem to support that - quite confusing.....

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET column2 = SUBSTRING(column1, 6, 12)
WHERE column2 IS NULL
```

or if you want to apply your WHERE clause (that you mention):

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET column2 = SUBSTRING(column1, 6, 12)
WHERE workorder = 12300000
```

However, your sample doesn't seem to use this WHERE clause.....

Comment: This is a the better answer as it will ork even if the first 5 characters vary. They don;t inthe sample but they may in other data or inthe future.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column2 = REPLACE(Column1,'B7CL-','')
WHERE Column2 ISNULL
```

or with the where clause

```
UPDATE Table 
SET Column2 = REPLACE(Column1,'B7CL-','') 
WHERE Column2 ISNULL
AND workorder=12300000
```

Comment: There's a certain risk that if the `B7CL-` string would appear elsewhere in your `column1` other than just the start, this statement would remove that occurence, too

Comment: And there is a risk that the string is not present at all, or even that it is shorter that your proposed 12 charaters in your answer...